# Is there any more easy and short version for concating array values depends on some case?

Tags: php

Is there any more easy and short version for concating array values depends on some case? `$places` is

```
$places[0] = [ 
   "option_name_en" => "Abovyan",
   "option_type_en" => "city",
   "option_name_general" => "Աբովյան",
   "option_type_general" => "քաղաք",
   "option_name_ru" => "Абовян",
   "option_type_ru" => "город",
   "option_value" => "50",
   "option_parent_name_en" => "Kotayk",
   "option_parent_type_en" => "region",
   "option_parent_name_general" => "Կոտայք",
   "option_parent_type_general" => "մարզ",
   "option_parent_name_ru" => "Котайк",
   "option_parent_type_ru" => "регион",
];

$places[1] = [ 
   "option_name_en" => "Agarak",
   "option_type_en" => "city",
   "option_name_general" => "Ագարակ",
   "option_type_general" => "քաղաք",
   "option_name_ru" => "Агарак",
   "option_type_ru" => "город",
   "option_value" => "57",
   "option_parent_name_en" => "Syunik",
   "option_parent_type_en" => "region",
   "option_parent_name_general" => "Սյունիք",
   "option_parent_type_general" => "մարզ",
   "option_parent_name_ru" => "Сюник",
   "option_parent_type_ru" => "регион",
];
```

I am doing like this but I need more easy version of array sorting because there can be more
languages.

```
foreach ($places as $place) {
   $placesArray['option_value'] = $place['option_value'];

   if (!is_null($place['option_parent_name_general'])) {
       foreach ($place as $key => $value) {
           if ($key === 'option_name_en' ) {
               $placesArray['option_title_en'] = $place['option_name_en'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_en'] . $this->getTranslator()->translate(' of ') . $place['option_parent_name_en'] . ' ' . $place['option_parent_type_en'] . ')';
           }

           if ($key === 'option_name_ru' ) {
               $placesArray['option_title_ru'] = $place['option_name_ru'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_ru'] . $this->getTranslator()->translate(' of ') . $place['option_parent_name_ru'] . ' ' . $place['option_parent_type_ru'] . ')';
           }

           if ($key === 'option_name_am' ) {
               $placesArray['option_title_am'] = $place['option_name_am'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_am'] . $this->getTranslator()->translate(' of ') . $place['option_parent_name_am'] . ' ' . $place['option_parent_type_am'] . ')';
           }

           if ($key === 'option_name_general' ) {
               $placesArray['option_title'] = $place['option_name_general'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_general'] . $this->getTranslator()->translate(' of ') . $place['option_parent_name_general'] . ' ' . $place['option_parent_type_general'] . ')';
           }
       }

       $placesSelectizeOptionsArray[] = $placesArray;
   } else {
       foreach ($place as $key => $value) {
           if ($key === 'option_name_en') {
               $placesArray['option_title_en'] = $place['option_name_en'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_en'] . ')';
           }

           if ($key === 'option_name_ru') {
               $placesArray['option_title_ru'] = $place['option_name_ru'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_ru'] . ')';
           }

           if ($key === 'option_name_am') {
               $placesArray['option_title_am'] = $place['option_name_am'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_am'] . ')';
           }

           if ($key === 'option_name_general') {
               $placesArray['option_title'] = $place['option_name_general'] . ' (' . $place['option_type_general'] . ')';
           }
       }

       $placesSelectizeOptionsArray[] = $placesArray;
   }
```

}

Resalt of `var_dump($placesSelectizeOptionsArray)` must be

```
$placesSelectizeOptionsArray[0] = [
   "option_value" => "50",
   "option_title_en" => "Abovyan (city of Kotayk region)",
   "option_title" => "Աբովյան (քաղաք of Կոտայք մարզ)",
   "option_title_ru" => "Абовян (город of Котайк регион)",
]; 

$placesSelectizeOptionsArray[1] => array:4 [
   "option_value" => "57"
   "option_title_en" => "Agarak (city of Syunik region)",
   "option_title" => "Ագարակ (քաղաք of Սյունիք մարզ)",
   "option_title_ru" => "Агарак (город of Сюник регион)",
];
```

Comment: But you are not apparently sorting anything

Comment: I am concating by language but when existing `option_parent_name_general` The concat is another . But there can be more languages

Comment: Still, it's not sorting, it's restructuring. I suggest you edit your question so it doesn't confuse future readers who are looking for array sorting problems.

Comment: A more *common* structure would be to have a overall level (say `option_title`) and then a sub array with keys `en`, `ru` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input array, this code will produce your example output. See comments for explanation.

```
// Output array.
$result = [];

// Loop over all places.
foreach ($places as $place)
{
    $naturalPlace = [];
    // Option_value can be copied
    $naturalPlace['option_value'] = $place['option_value'];
    
    // For each language/locale, define a suffix and loop over each of them to construct a natural label.
    foreach (['en' => '_en', 'general' => '', 'ru' => '_ru'] as $key => $fieldSuffix)
    {
        // Expand the $key to avoid having an if block for every language.
        // Adding more languages will be as easy as adding them to your input array and this foreach.
        $naturalPlace["option_title$fieldSuffix"] = $place["option_name_$key"] . ' (' . $place["option_type_$key"] . ' of ' . $place["option_parent_name_$key"] . ' ' . $place["option_parent_type_$key"] . ')';
    }
    
    // Aggregate into final result.
    $result[] = $naturalPlace;
}

var_dump($result);
/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["option_value"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["option_title_en"]=>
    string(31) "Abovyan (city of Kotayk region)"
    ["option_title"]=>
    string(52) "Աբովյան (քաղաք of Կոտայք մարզ)"
    ["option_title_ru"]=>
    string(54) "Абовян (город of Котайк регион)"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["option_value"]=>
    string(2) "57"
    ["option_title_en"]=>
    string(30) "Agarak (city of Syunik region)"
    ["option_title"]=>
    string(52) "Ագարակ (քաղաք of Սյունիք մարզ)"
    ["option_title_ru"]=>
    string(52) "Агарак (город of Сюник регион)"
  }
}
*/
```